# how to set up default_qty_value using user input value in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

basically I want to dynamically change the size of leverage position using user input, I have variable LEVERAGE in default_qty_value as shown below:

```
//@version=5
LEVERAGE = input.int(1, minval=1, step=1) 

strategy('YTStrategy', overlay=true, margin_long=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=LEVERAGE*100, currency=currency.USD, process_orders_on_close=true)
```

the compiler keeps reporting error :

> Cannot call 'strategy' with argument 'default_qty_value'='call
> 'operator *' (input int)'. An argument of 'input int' type was used
> but a 'const float' is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `default_qty_value` must be known at compile time. You cannot use a user input for that.

You can change your variable into a regular one:

```
LEVERAGE = 1.0
```

Or use the strategy settings to configure those options.

Comment: use the strategy settings on property is the solution...Thanks for reminding me of this...I'm totally nerd LMAO THX Alot BRO~

Comment: If my post answered your question, please consider accepting it as an answer so we don't need to come back to this question again.

Comment: i dont have the right to cast a vote b/c my reputation is less than 15..Thx for the help

Comment: Please see [how to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)